# Class has to create new object internally, which can't be accessed from unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit5

We have a class whose purpose is to change the values in some fields of a received object and keep the values of its other fields

```
public void process(SomeType someObject) {
  SomeType modifiedObject = modifyObject(someObject);
  nextClass.process(modifiedObject);
}

private SomeType modifyObject(SomeType someObject) {
  String someValueFromServiceCall = someService.getSomeValue(...);
  SomeType modifiedObject = new SomeType.Builder()
                                        .withSomeFieldValuesFromSomeObjectItself(...)
                                        .withSomeFieldValuesFromServiceCall(someValueFromServiceCall)
                                        .build();
  return modifiedObject;
}
```

`SomeType` is a legacy class which we can create using only its builder class and it has no setter methods. This means we cannot modify the received `someObject` itself, but have to build and return a new `SomeType` object from `modifyObject()`, which the main method then can pass on for processing to the next class

However this seems to raise problems during unit testing. We don't seem to be able to access the internal `modifiedObject` from the unit test class and such as we don't seem to be able to do expects/asserts on it

```
SomeType someObject = createSomeObjectForTest();
expect(someServiceMock.getSomeValue(...)).andReturn(SOME_VALUE);
expect(nextClassMock.process(someObject)).andReturn(...); //this is not someObject, but the new internal modifiedObject created within underTest
underTest.process(someObject);
assertEquals(someObject.getSomeField(), SOME_VALUE); //this is not someObject, but the new internal modifiedObject created within underTest
```

Comment: your test should not mock that. you should make your param to your method you're testing so, that the modifyObject method creates a valid instance (which behaves like you want it to for that flow). if you go mock that, you'll leave that private method untested, which is a code smell (or worse)

Comment: @Stultuske: The `modifyObject()` method creates a valid instance, it simply wires up `SomeType.Builder` using most of the corresponding field values from the `someObject` instance and a couple other field values stemming from simple calculations. The flow works correctly (covered by several end-to-end acceptance and manual tests), the question is whether unit testing can be solved in any way. Please explain what you mean by "your test should not mock that"; i.e. how are we able to trigger `underTest.process()` without creating a test `someObject` beforehand

Comment: you shouldn't. not even sure you can, depending on the code you've shown. if there is a servicecall in that modifyObject method, and that service is declared as instance member, you could mock that, I guess

Comment: @Stultuske: There is indeed a service call in `modifyObject`, which is mocked out in the test. I updated the question text with the related code lines. This does not seem to make any difference from the question point of view though. The value returned from the service is being utilized by `SomeType.Builder`, but at the end of the day we still have to build a new `SomeType` instance which is not accessible from the test.

Comment: You probably mocked `nextClass`, so you can use an `ArgumentCaptor` to intercept what the argument of its `process` method was. It's the modified object.

Comment: @daniu: Yes, `nextClass` is mocked in the test. Never used `ArgumentCaptor` before, but let me give it a try, will report back

Comment: @Stultuske testing private methods is a code smell. Test public contract.

Comment: @Antoniossss ehm ... duh. they should be tested through the test of the public methods. if you mock them for all tests, you risk signing off on possibly faulty code

Comment: *they should be tested through the test of the public methods* exactly, thats why you dont test them explicitly. Why would anyone mock private method is the real mistery to me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use the `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
// mock and make sure all fields required for modify are set
SomeType arg = create(); 
ArgumentCaptor<SomeType> captor = ArgumentCaptor. forClass(SomeType.class);

sut.process(arg) ;

verify (nextClass). process(captor.capture());
SomeType modified = captor.get();
```

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I tested it out, we are actually using EasyMock and its `Capture` class covers the same idea. The test works now as expected. I appreciate your help.